# Detecting Image on Page Load

Tags: phantomjs

I want to test whether a particular image loaded by a JavaScript on Page Load. 
**This image is loaded after a particular JS library gets executed**.

For reference : I am using a utility from The JS Library - **Zurb's Foundation** which detects the view port , user agent and loads appropriate image.

1. When the page is downloaded - the **"src"** attribute in the Img tag is **empty**
2. When the foundation js executes it loads the image by adding the src tag on the img tag.

In the onResourceReceived - this image never shows up.

In the onLoadFinished - the image tag attribute src is not present.

How to tackle this scenario when the image load is triggered by a Javascript library. ?

*Basically the test case i want to execute is : Test whether the Right Quality Image is being loaded based on the Device.*

Comment: Have you checked (with screenshots) that the image is loaded at all? Can you share the code of script and test page?

Comment: Remember that there is a difference between `img.src` and `img.getAttribute("src")`

Comment: @Vaviloff- solved the problem using waitFor logic